# Given the IANA entry is known, how do I find a specific dates offset (daylight vs standard)?

Tags: go, timezone

I have a list of date strings that appear in this format without any time zone or offset information:

```
[
   "2019-04-30T12:34:00.000",  // In 2019, DST started in March 10, 2019, so this should have the appropriate DST offset
   "2017-11-20T13:45:00.000"   // In 2017, DST ended on November 5, 2017 so this should have the appropriate standard time offset
]
```

I know the IANA region (eg, `America/New_York`) that these dates and times were created in, but I cannot figure out how to dynamically generate the appropriate offset given this information using go and the `time` package.

I have thought about the following:

1. Appending a hardcoded value to the end of the date string (ie, `"2019-04-30T12:34:00.000" + "-04:00`)
2. Write custom logic to determine if a date falls within the boundary of standard or daylight savings time

However, these solutions only work for some dates or the logic becomes exceedingly complicated.

Comment: [time.ParseInLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation)

Comment: @Peter thanks for that reference - it simplifies the logic much better than my initial solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    Chicago, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Chicago")

    t := time.Date(2019, time.March, 1, 12, 30, 0, 0, Chicago)
    log.Print(t)       // 2019-03-01 12:30:00 -0600 CST
    log.Print(t.UTC()) // 2019-03-01 18:30:00 +0000 UTC
    t = time.Date(2019, time.November, 2, 12, 30, 0, 0, Chicago)
    log.Print(t)       // 2019-11-02 12:30:00 -0500 CDT
    log.Print(t.UTC()) // 2019-11-02 17:30:00 +0000 UTC
}
```

go playground @ https://play.golang.org/p/nP28y9jSDAk

An even cleaner solution by leveraging a custom layout and [time.LoadLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

)

func main() {
    Chicago, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Chicago")

    cdt, _ := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999", "2019-04-30T12:34:00.000", Chicago)


    fmt.Println(cdt)
    fmt.Println(cdt.UTC())

    cst, _ := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999", "2017-11-20T13:45:00.000", Chicago)

    fmt.Println(cst)
    fmt.Println(cst.UTC())
}
```

go playground @ https://play.golang.org/p/3Ai4qVz0af5